# How to import csv file with objects to Cassandra

Tags: database, cassandra

I have a question regarding importing a CSV file which has some of its fields are objects, I have created the types for those objects but I don't know how to import the CSV's objects' data to cassandra types.

For an example, I have a house table that has id, name and pet(pet is an object). I have create a type for pet(name, age), in my CSV file, it has 2 columns called pet.name and pet.age and I want to import those data to the pet type. Am I able to do that? Sorry I'm new to Cassandra.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DataStax Bulk Loader](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/dsbulkAbout.html) tool (DSBulk) to bulk load data in CSV format to a Cassandra table. It supports loading data into columns with user-defined types (UDTs).

Here are some references with examples to help you get started quickly:

- Blog - [DSBulk Intro + Loading data](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-introduction-and-loading)
- Blog - [More DSBulk Loading examples](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-more-loading)
- Blog - [Counting records with DSBulk](https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting)
- Docs - [Loading data examples](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/dsbulk/reference/dsbulkLoad.html)
- Answered questions - [DS Community](https://community.datastax.com/topics/dsbulk.html)

DSBulk is open-source so it's free to use. Cheers!